# The translation operator for continuous functions is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Let $\mathcal C^0_{2\pi}$ be the space of countinuous, $2\pi$-period functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, endowed with the norm
$$||f||_{\mathcal C^0_{2\pi}}=\max_{x\in[0,2\pi]}|f(x)|.$$
For each $f\in\mathcal C^0_{2\pi}$ and each $y\in\mathbb R$, let
$$\tau_yf:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C,\quad x\mapsto f(x-y).$$

I found a lemma which states: for each $f\in\mathcal C^0_{2\pi}$,
$$\lim_{y\to0}||\tau_yf-f||_{\mathcal C^0_{2\pi}}=0.$$

I would like to ask if my proof of this lemma is correct, it looks too simple.
By definition, we have 
$$||\tau_yf-f||_{\mathcal C^0_{2\pi}}=\max_{x\in[0,2\pi]}|\tau_yf(x)-f(x)|=\max_{x\in[0,2\pi]}|f(x-y)-f(x)|.$$ Let $x_0$ be a point where this maximum is reached, that is
$$\max_{x\in[0,2\pi]}|f(x-y)-f(x)|=|f(x_0-y)-f(x_0)|.$$
Since $f$ is continuous in $x_0$, we have
$$\lim_{y\to0}|f(x_0-y)-f(x_0)|=0.$$
Is this proof ok? Thank you very much!

Comment: Your proof is OK. The statement is just saying that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: By the way, there is still one thing to say: $x_0$ varies with $y$, so you need to prove the uniformly continuity first :) I assumed you already knew it when I posted the first comment.